# How to Simply pass a property value from TS file of one component to another

Tags: typescript, angular6

one.component.ts

```
rightmenuDetails=[
  {
    text: valueicon: img
  },
  {
    text: valueicon: img
  }
]
```

two.component.html

```
<p>{{rightmenuDetails.text}}</p>
```

Is this possible in a simple way?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this depending on your use case, if you want the pass the data in a child-component you may use the @Input() annotation and property binding (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties), you may also use a service to pass data trough multiple loose components - please supply more information on how those two components are linked together

Comment: Are those two components are siblings *[parent-child]*?

Comment: no two are child thats my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a service in a rather quick 'n dirty manner.

Build a service containing a string-variable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {
   public text: string = '';

   constructor() { }
}
```

You have to import the service into your Module and provide it.

```
import { ComponentA } from './component-a.ts';
import { ComponentB } from './component-b.ts';
import { SimpleService } from './simple.service.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  ],
  imports: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  ],
  providers: [
      SimpleService
  ]

})
export class XYZModule { }
```

Then one component sets the value and the other reads it.

ComponentA

```
import { SimpleService } from './simple.service.ts';

constructor(private simpleService: SimpleService) { }

setText(text: string): {
    this.simpleService.text = text;
}
```

ComponentB

TS-file

```
import { SimpleService } from './simple.service.ts';

constructor(private simpleService: SimpleService) { }
```

HTML-file

```
<p>{{simpleService.text}}</p>
```

That's it.